# is MXML file in flex an example of MVC design pattern ?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I was wondering if mxml file used in flex is an example of mvc design pattern.  As it contains the view information in tag format. So, we can probably call it logic related to  "View" .

But, in that case what would you call the code lying within  tags in the same mxml file  ?

V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MXML file is definitely a part of "**View**", you are right, but you cannot call it MVC pattern unless you also introduce the "**Model**" and "**Controller**".
Everything contained in the MXML file is "logic related to View", not only the regular tags but also the **Script** tag.

Check the [Robotlegs framework](http://www.robotlegs.org/), or [PureMVC](http://puremvc.org/) (amongst others) if you want to see what a MVC architecture look like.

For example, here is the conceptual diagram of PureMVC:
http://npacemo.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/puremvc-conceptual-diagram.jpg

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

MXML is a declarative XML syntax that is converted by the compiler into an ActionScript class.

The following links may help you understand better:

http://www.southsearepublic.org/article/1662/read/cheat_notes_for_mxml_and_flexs_state/flash_actionscript_and_mxml_in_flex/

http://blog.vivisectingmedia.com/2008/04/the-flex-code-behind-pattern/